# Python : Only one element return in tuple return by find_closest

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, tuples, closest

I've this code who create a rectangle an say if there is something else near of him :

```
def creaRect(event):
    #rect = Rectangle.Rectangle(canvas, event, CanWidth=Width, CanHeight=Height)
    width, height = 25, 25
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    x1 = int(x-width/2)
    y1 = int(y-height/2)
    x2 = int(x+width/2)
    y2 = int(y+height/2)
    rect = canvas.create_rectangle((x1, y1, x2, y2), outline="red", width=1, tags="bloc")
    Rectangle.OidRect.append(rect)

    near = canvas.find_closest(x, y, 200)
    print(len(near))
```

But the lenght of the tuple return by find_closest is every time 1, while i create many rectangles on the same position or really near.
For me find_closest should return a tuple with the id of all the items around x, y coordinates in a range of 200.
Is it something i don't understand or do wrong ?

Comment: without any experience on tkinter: I would think `closest` is a superlativ -- therefore it should return just one -- the superlativ. Otherwise the function should be named `find_close` -- but as I said: I have no experience with tkinter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation about `find_closest()` [here](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/pydoc/Tkinter.Canvas.html)

> find_closest(self, x, y, halo=None, start=None)
>
> Return item which is closest to pixel at X, Y.
>   If several match take the top-most.
>   All items closer than HALO are considered overlapping (all are
>   closests). If START is specified the next below this tag is taken.

So `find_closest()` will only give you the one closest item. If you want to find multiple items within a distance from a point (which is what is sounds like you were going for) try:

> find_overlapping(x1, y1, x2, y2) 
>   Finds all items that overlap the given rectangle, or that are completely enclosed by it.
>   
> x1 - Left edge. 
>   
> y1 - Upper edge. 
>   
> x2 - Right edge. 
>   
> y2 - Lower edge. 
>   
> Returns:
>   
> A tuple containing all matching items.